# A scenario where static virtual methods make sense

Tags: c#, static, virtual

I know that `virtual` and `static` methods are opposing concepts, but I think that it could make sense sometimes to use them together. There have been quite a bunch of similiar question on SO on this topic, but the following scenario has not been covered yet.

There's a C# interface that looks like this:

```
interface IVertexMeshLoader
{
    VertexMesh LoadFromFile(string fname);
}
```

An implementation of that could look like this:

```
class VertexMeshLoaderObj : IVertexMeshLoader
{
    public VertexMesh LoadFromFile(string fname) { .. }
}
```

Now I would like to be able to call method without an object instance, but I cannot make the `LoadFromFile()` method static, because it implements the interface.

The best solution I worked out so far is to write a static method `LoadFromFileStatic()` that contains the actual code. The `LoadFromFile()` then just calls it. Not very pretty, imho.

I could also create an instance of `VertexMeshLoadObj` every time I want to call the method, but that is even worse.

Are there better ways? Thanks :-)

Comment: You could have an abstract base class with a static `LoadFromFile` method, or are you anticipating that each implementation of `IVertexMeshLoader` might have a different implementation of the static method?

Comment: IMO if an instance method can, sometimes, become a static class method, maybe this could be a sign of a design flaw.

Comment: The `LoadFromFile` method is different in each implementation, yes.

Comment: How would you use this?  The benefit of interfaces is that they are types, so objects can be passed around under the interface type.  How would you pass around un-instantiated classes?  And if you wouldn't, then the interface provides you no benefit, as you could just refer directly to the class name you wanted in each case.

Comment: In a different use case for example. A manager class contains different instances of the interface, but sometimes I want to access the method directly using a static call.

Comment: "I could also create an instance of `VertexMeshLoadObj` every time I want to call the method, but that is even worse." - what? What's wrong with creating an instance when you want to call the method?

Comment: The method is static per se, but the instance is required in order to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option.  Provide an explicit implementation of the interface which just calls the static method.  It allows them to have the same name

```
class VertexMeshLoaderObj : IVertexMeshLoader
{
  VertexMesh IVertexMeshLoader.LoadFromFile(string fname) { 
    LoadFromFile(fname);
  }
  public static VertexMesh LoadFromFile(fname) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The `public` is not valid for explicit implementation, but it works like a breeze without. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, create a singleton instance of IVertexMeshLoader and access that

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're only interested in the vtable of the object and not in the actual members, you need an object instance to know what method to call.

So even if the actual implementation doesn't seem to depend on the instance, it in fact does.

You're not using "static virtual" methods but really *virtual* ones.